# How to find the program that generates a file in ROS?

Tags: file, ros, launch

My launch file uses the file `pivotFiles/art_to_kinect2_1.txt` in ROS. How do I find the program that generates this file so that the launch file could use it??

```
<param name="fileName" value="$(find pivotFiles/art_to_kinect2_1.txt" />
```

Comment: You are missing a ) in your parameter.
And how do you mean "generates a file"? This file is not auto-generated but it already exists.  After using "param" you create a parameter on the ROSparam server with the name "fileName" and the value being the location of the input file I guess.

Comment: Also check: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam

Comment: In what way does your launch file use that text file?

Comment: @LakshmiDevarajNair I think it's misleading to say your launch file does these calculations and overwrites, do you mean the launch file starts a node that does this processing? And the generated file seems independent of the launch file. All the launch file does is start nodes and load parameters and such. You essentially just want to know what program on your computer is producing this text file?

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command will only be looking for ROS packages available in your environment. So if your text file is stored in a ROS package, for example:

```
/home/user/catkin_ws/src/my_package/pivotFiles/art_to_kinect2_1.txt
```

then if you just want to load the *path* of that file to the ROS parameter server, you can do

```
<param name="fileName" value="$(find my_package)/pivotFiles/art_to_kinect2_1.txt"/>
```

Or if you want to load the *contents* of the file, you can do

```
<param name="fileContents" command="cat $(find my_package)/pivotFiles/art_to_kinect2_1.txt"/>
```

If your file is not in a ROS package, then I would recommend using `optenv` or `arg`, both [roslaunch substitution args](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args). `opt_env` tries to use an [environment variable](https://phoenixts.com/blog/environment-variables-in-linux/) if set, and if not uses a default value. For example, you can do

```
<param name="fileName" value="$(optenv CONFIG_PATH /home/user/some_folder/pivotFiles)/art_to_kinect2_1.txt"/>
```

Then you can configure the environment variable `CONFIG_PATH` as needed. The option I usually prefer is `arg` because you can pass the path in from the commandline when you run roslaunch. In your launch file you can put

```
<arg name="config_path" default="/home/user/some_folder/pivotFiles"/>
```

and then in the param tag do

```
<param name="fileName" value="$(arg config_path)/art_to_kinect2_1.txt"/>
```

The advantage then is that at the commandline you can do

```
roslaunch my_package my_launch_file.launch config_path:=/home/user/some_other_folder
```

and that will switch the configuration path used in the launch file. `opt_env` is essentially doing the same thing, but through environment variables, and I typically don't want to mess with those when I can pass it directly to the file with `arg`.